# How to get the image to cell in TableViewer?

Tags: java, jface

I created a TableViewer ( jface ).

I want in some cases to hidden the image.( to control on the visible of the image ) 
The logic is done in different class and not in the tableViewer.
How I can get the cell and then the to control the image visibility ? .( I know the name of the cell and it is always the first cell in the tableviewer )
//The gridViewer Class

```
     public class MyGridViewer extends TableViewer {
     public MyGridViewer (Composite parent) {
    super(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);

    final Table table = this.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    this.setContentProvider(new MyModelProvider());

        }
      }


     @Override
    protected void inputChanged(Object input, Object oldInput) {

    removeColumn();



        tableCol = new TableViewerColumn(this, SWT.NONE);
        column = tableCol.getColumn();
        column.setText(dataColumnHeader.getName());
        column.setWidth(100);
        column.setResizable(true);
        column.setMoveable(true);
        tableCol.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                DataRow r = (DataRow) element;
                DataCell c = r.getDataCellByName(dataColumnHeader.getName());
                if (c != null && c.getValue() != null) {
                    return c.getValue().toString();
                }
                return null;
            }
             @Override
             public Image getImage(Object element) {
                   //Add my imgae
             }
        });



     editingSupport = new StringCellEditingSupport(this, dataColumnHeader);
     tableCol.setEditingSupport(editingSupport);
        super.inputChanged(input, oldInput);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColumnLabelProvider` has a `getImage` method similar to the `getText` method:

```
public Image getImage(Object element);
```

Comment: Hi I added my logic to tableCol.setLabelProvider() with override on getImage. Now the problem that in someCase I want in my code to remove the image ( visible = false) . How I can get the cell and then to update the image ?

Comment: Call `TableViewer.update(object)` to make the viewer update an object (the object is the value returned by the content provider). You may need to use `TableViewer.setUseHashlookup(true)`

Comment: Can I just get the value without call to update ? if I will call to the update Can I move any parameters  ? does the object mean to the row or to the cell or to the column ?

Comment: if I will call to the update Can I move any parameters - I meant other parameters beside the object

Comment: `TableViewer.update` will call your label provider to get updated information.

Comment: two issues : 1.I didn't understand what should be the object that I need to pass 2. If I want to add logic meaning from one class to enable the icon and from other class disable the icon how i can control on it.Can I move any parameters ?